# Entity Framework Base Repository

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a base repository for use with Entity Framework 4.0 and having some trouble.  In this code below, why is it not possible to do this in one line?

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    IEnumerable<T> allCustomers = this.GetAll<T>();
    IEnumerable<T> result = allCustomers.Where(filter.Compile());

    return result;
}
```

Won't this result in 2 SQL statements: one without a where clause that retrieves all rows, and one with a where clause that only retrieves the rows that match the predicate?

How can this be done with a single SQL statement?  I can't get it to compile if I try to cast the filter.Compile() to Func<Customer, bool>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.GetAll<T>().Where(filter);
```

If you want to add additional conditions and execute them on database side (using SQL), GetAll() should return `IQueryable`. `IQueryable` version of where takes `Expression`, so there is no need to call `Compile()`. EF will take expression and translate it to SQL.

Using `IEnumerable` version of `Where` executes query and retrieves all rows in the table before applying filter.

Comment: Yep that worked!  Thanks so much!  return (this.GetAll<T>() as IQueryable<T>).Where(filter);

Comment: @Andy: That is great, but still 'GetAll<T>()` should return `IQueryable<T>` and should not need casting. If `GetAll<T>()` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, you select all rows from the table and filter on application side.